# Lightest x64 to install on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I have a Little tablet (Z3735F 64 bit - 4 cores, 1.33-1.8Ghz, 2 GB RAM) with x86 Windows 8 installed.

Then I installed a x64 Lubuntu in a virtual machine, and set it to use 512 MB RAM.

It works great, I use the x64 Lubuntu to run a sdk (only available for x64).

But I was wondering if there is a lighter Linux because that Lubuntu used 5.2 GB of my hard disk, and I'd love to use less than 512 MB of RAM. Using the vdi image on a USB, makes it too hot.

I only want to use:

- The sdk (it is just some libs and makefiles, cmake, gcc, nothing very complex).
- Some kind of window management and text editor (the simplest one).
- Guest additions to use shared folder with windows.
- Internet connection.

Another possibility would be to uninstall things from Lubuntu to make it smaller, and then resize the vdi image, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate the Minimal Install, which lets you pick only the packages you want.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Minimal install filled up 2 GB, even without desktop enviroment, and used 400 MB RAM... Lububtu is using 200 with desktop... Still the best one.. if i could reduce lubuntu size to less than 1 GB, it would be perfect.

Comment: I'm a Lubuntu user myself.

Comment: @Mills, you must have installed in an inefficient way from the `mini.iso`. It can be made much smaller both in RAM and in the [virtual] drive. See this link, [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative). I don't think that this particular system works in VirtualBox, because it needs special drivers, so you should install from a `mini.iso` and add the program packages, that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Antix - ALOT smaller and even lighter than lubuntu

Comment: Antix is not Ubuntu, thus off-topic here, sorry...

Comment: @Fabby I don't know what it would mean for an *answer* to be off-topic, but our community consensus as judged by votes [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14911/22949) and [there](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11725/22949) is that we do not actually prohibit recommending other operating systems, and that answers that do so are *sometimes* reasonable. I don't think this answer is good as it stands, because it lacks detail (see the answers to those meta questions), but it could potentially be improved. This answer *might* be regarded as not answering the OP's question and deleted for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience using linux, you could use Arch Linux, there you only have to install the rools you really need. Also you have free choice of your desktop environment, so you could use xfce, or if you really want to savr on RAM, takr a look at openbox.

Comment: Thanks I tried arc and i was not able to do much with it.. :). Lubuntu is still the best I found, it works with openbox, and it just uses 120-200 MB ram. The bad thing about lubuntu, is the instalation was about 4 GB and i'm sure i don't need most of that.

Comment: @Mills, a rather big part of the size on the disk is the swap partition/file. You can make it smaller. You can also select Lubuntu Core (when starting from `mini.iso`), which skips a lot of application programs.